# Reopening the LibGdx Android APP not drawing the screens properly

Tags: android, android-layout, libgdx, game-engine

I have created an android App using the LibGdx framework. Whenever I flash it to my android device it works perfectly. But When I close the app and open it freshly, the App shows the black and white rectangle boxes instead of the image. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue ?
[image]

Code

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class CatchEggs implements ApplicationListener {
    public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800;
    public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 480;
    public static final float FRAME_SPEED = .1f;
    public static int shortWastedCount,eggCatchedCount;
    private int score;
    private String yourScoreName;
    BitmapFont yourBitmapFontName;

    public static ArrayList<Texture> TextureArray = new ArrayList<Texture>();  

    private OrthographicCamera camera;  
    private SpriteBatch batch; 
    private AnimatedSprite basket;
    private EggLayManager EggLayManager;
    private Music gameMusic;
    private Hen hen1,hen2,hen3;
    private CollisionManager collisionManager;
    private boolean isGameOver = false;
    @Override
    public void create() {      

        //Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false); 
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        batch = new SpriteBatch(); 
        Sprite basketSprite = new Sprite(TextureManager.BASKET_TEXTURE);
        basket = new AnimatedSprite(basketSprite,FRAME_SPEED,1,1);
        basket.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0);

        EggLayManager = new EggLayManager(TextureManager.EGG_TEXTURE);   

        TextureArray.add(TextureManager.GREEN_EGG_TEXTURE);
        TextureArray.add(TextureManager.PINK_EGG_TEXTURE);
        TextureArray.add(TextureManager.GOLDEN_EGG_TEXTURE);
        TextureArray.add(TextureManager.EGG_TEXTURE); 

        hen1 = new Hen(TextureManager.HEN_TEXTURE, EggLayManager,0,SCREEN_WIDTH/3);
        hen2 = new Hen(TextureManager.HEN_TEXTURE, EggLayManager,SCREEN_WIDTH/3,2*SCREEN_WIDTH/3);
        hen3 = new Hen(TextureManager.HEN_TEXTURE, EggLayManager,2*SCREEN_WIDTH/3,SCREEN_WIDTH);

        collisionManager = new CollisionManager(basket,EggLayManager); 

        gameMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/game-music.mp3"));
        gameMusic.setVolume(.25f);
        gameMusic.setLooping(true);
        gameMusic.play();

        score = 0;
        yourScoreName = "score: 0";
        yourBitmapFontName = new BitmapFont(); 

        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("data/font.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 27;
        yourBitmapFontName = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
        generator.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose(); 
        gameMusic.dispose();
        yourBitmapFontName.dispose();  
        gameMusic.dispose();
        yourBitmapFontName.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.BACKGROUND.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.BASKET_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.GAME_OVER.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.EGG_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.EGG_BREAK_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.HEN_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.SCORE_BOARD_BOUNDARY.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.GOLDEN_EGG_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.PINK_EGG_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureManager.GREEN_EGG_TEXTURE.dispose(); 
        TextureArray.clear();  
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin(); 
        batch.draw(TextureManager.BACKGROUND,0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        showImage(TextureManager.SCORE_BOARD_BOUNDARY,SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - TextureManager.SCORE_BOARD_BOUNDARY.getWidth() / 2, 
                                                       SCREEN_HEIGHT - TextureManager.SCORE_BOARD_BOUNDARY.getHeight());

        hen1.draw(batch);
        hen2.draw(batch);
        hen3.draw(batch);
        EggLayManager.draw(batch); 
        basket.draw(batch); 

        showScore();   
        showGameOver(); 

        batch.end(); 
        handleInput(); 

        if(!isGameOver) {
            basket.move();
            hen1.update();  
            hen2.update();
            hen3.update();
            EggLayManager.update();  
            collisionManager.handleCollisions(); 
        }   

        if(basket.isCaught()) {
            isGameOver = false;
        }else{  
            isGameOver = true;
        }

    }

    private void showGameOver() {
        if(shortWastedCount>=21) isGameOver = true; 

        if(isGameOver){ 
            showImage(TextureManager.GAME_OVER,SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - TextureManager.GAME_OVER.getWidth() / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - TextureManager.GAME_OVER.getHeight() / 2);
        }
    }

    private void showImage(Texture t,int x, int y) { 
        batch.draw(t, x, y);  
    }

    private void showScore() { 

        showImage(TextureManager.EGG_TEXTURE,       39 - TextureManager.EGG_TEXTURE.getWidth()/2       , 750);
        showImage(TextureManager.EGG_BREAK_TEXTURE, 39 - TextureManager.EGG_BREAK_TEXTURE.getWidth()/2 , 700);

        yourScoreName = " " + eggCatchedCount; 
        yourBitmapFontName.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
        yourBitmapFontName.draw(batch, yourScoreName, 72, 777);         

        yourScoreName = " " + shortWastedCount; 
        yourBitmapFontName.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
        yourBitmapFontName.draw(batch, yourScoreName, 72, 725);
    }

    private void handleInput() {
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            if(isGameOver) {
                basket.setCaught(true);
                isGameOver = false;
                shortWastedCount=eggCatchedCount=0;
            }

            Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPosition);

            if(touchPosition.x > basket.getX()) {
                basket.moveRight(touchPosition);
            }
            else{
                basket.moveLeft(touchPosition);
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Comment: do you dispose things properly in the `dispose()` callback of the `ApplicationAdapter` or the `Game` (whichever you use)?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question and added the code for reference.

Comment: what happens if you use `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` instead?

Comment: no effect.. still same

Comment: try commenting out `showScore()` method call in `render()`

Comment: did it, but the issue still there

Comment: ugh. copy out lines of the code in `render()` one by one until it stops happening.

Comment: I tried with only one draw statement.. Still it is same. 1st time it shows the background on pressing back and opening the app again shows only the white screen with music
batch.draw(TextureManager.BACKGROUND,0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);

Comment: Your code looks like you are not disposing of textures.

Comment: Code updated with the dispose() on all the textures. Still the same issue

Comment: Try setting your TextureManager to null and assets manager if you have one in it. All in all clear up all static variables in dispose.

Comment: Veljko, Thanks for saving my time. You are right, After I have removed the static fields everything went fine. Please post this as answer I will accept it . Thank you again

Comment: @Veljko please post comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your TextureManager to null and assets manager if you have one in it. All in all clear up all static variables in dispose.

Glad that I helped you.
Cheers.

Comment: As the code has many sub classes, I am not able to post the complete code. But what I did is creates a dispose() method in all sub classes where I dispose all the texture fields of the class and set it to null. these dispose() are called in the main class. thats it. Now it works like a charm !