# After closing the App Texture is not being drawn anymore

Tags: libgdx

I can draw the texture but, when I press back(also close the game) and open it again the texture is black(it responds to the touches but the image is whole black).

However when I kill all activities from my Android device and open the game again the texture can be drawn.

I am very new with libgdx where is my mistake here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scene2d tables turn black on one phone after a few game resets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186103/scene2d-tables-turn-black-on-one-phone-after-a-few-game-resets)

Comment: yep somehow helps, I was searching my issue on the net but couldn't find these questions. Thanks for pointing me out that there are possible duplucates.

Comment: these threads didn't help me but this one did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764168/reopening-the-libgdx-android-app-not-drawing-the-screens-properly